# Laravel auth redirect 302 on live server

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Why is laravel Auth not working on live server? It's always returning redirect 302,

I've surfed all along google, StackOverflow, changing my config/session domain to my domain, change my .env APP_URL, using `redirect()->intended()`, but it's still not working.

Here is my code :

LoginController :

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt([
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password'  => $request->password,
        ])) {
            if (Auth::user()->id_level_user == 1) {
                echo json_encode(url('/superadmin'));
            } elseif (Auth::user()->id_level_user == 2) {
                echo json_encode(url('/admin'));
            } else {
                echo json_encode(url('/superadmin'));
            }
        } else {
            $msg = ['error', 'Username / Pasword Salah'];
            echo json_encode($msg, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        }
    }
```

Login view, I'm logging in using ajax

```
<form action="{{ url('/dologin') }}" method="POST" id="form-login">
     @csrf
     <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-4">
               <input type="username" class="form-control input-lg" id="username" name="username" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 ">
               <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="error_kode" id="login-error" >
                         
                    </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mb-4" id="btn-login">LOGIN</button>
          </div>
     </div>
</form>
$('#form-login').submit(function(){
     $.ajax({
          url: '{{ url('/dologin') }}',
          type: 'ajax',
          method : 'post',
          dataType : 'json',
          data : {
               username : $('#username').val(),
               password : $('#password').val()
          },
          beforeSend: function(){
               $('#form-login-body').LoadingOverlay('show');
               $('#username').prop('disable',true);
               $('#password').prop('disable',true);
               $('#btn-login').prop('disable',true);
          },
          success: function(data){
               if(data[0]=="error"){
                    swal('Login Gagal',{
                         icon : "error",
                         timer: 800,
                         button : false
                    });
                    $('#login-error').html(data[1]);
                    $('#username').prop('disable',false);
                    $('#password').prop('disable',false);
                    $('#btn-login').prop('disable',false);
                    $('#form-login-body').LoadingOverlay('hide');
               }else{
                    $('#form-login-body').LoadingOverlay('hide');
                    swal('Login Sukses',{
                         icon : "success",
                         timer: 800,
                         button: false,
                    });
                    setTimeout(function() {window.location.replace(data)}, 1000);
               }
          },
          error: function(e){
               swal(e,{
                    icon : 'error',
                    timer : 800,
                    button : false,
               });
          }
     })
     return false;
})
```

RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id_level_user == 1) {
            return redirect()->intended('/superadmin');
        } elseif (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id_level_user == 2) {
            // return redirect(url('/admin'));
            return redirect()->intended('/admin');
        } elseif (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id_level_user == 3) {
            return redirect()->intended('/operator');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

It's working just fine in localhost, but suddenly not working when I upload it on my hosting. Hope somebody can help me

Thank you

Comment: You should not have `echo` in a controller method. Use built-in functions like `response()->json()` to return JSON with proper headers. You can also set response code; a failure should not return 200.

Comment: @miken32 okay that's my fault, but it still returns Redirect 302 after I change that

Comment: have you checked permissions on the storage folder? It sounds like Laravel cannot create any session files.

Comment: and what is the value of APP_URL in your .env live production?

Comment: @SachinKumar how to check the permission on storage folder? 
the APP_URL is my domain

Comment: For checking permission, it depends on the operating system. And share the url if possible. And also which url is generated for login form

Comment: my web is on https://eprop.aspire.my.id and the hosting server is running on linux

Comment: run the following command "sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache && sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache" to give the permission and I hope the login URL(i.e form URL) is correct.

Comment: @SachinKumar I make sure the login URL is right because it's working just fine in localhost. I'll try to check the permission first

Comment: So what about the permission then. Does it works?